# Can't access the code behind using ajax post in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

This is my code behind:

[image]

This is my KO Script:

[image]

this is the result when I click my submit button
[image]

I there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. How have you set up your authentication?

Comment: I tried to put this 
<location path="SupplyPoints.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />

Comment: Is this a vanilla web application, or is it running through a CMS of some sort?

Comment: nope it's a plain asp.net project. here's the source https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3037520/GovernmentTest.zip

Comment: See this post here is complete solution to this problem,
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have downloaded your solution and got it working

In `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` you have the following line which needs to be removed:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

Also your web method needs to be `static`

Comment: still got the auth fail message

Answer (score 2):

In `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` 
Change

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

to

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

If the web method is not static in code behind, it will not work.
If you really want to continue using code behind, you can do so by creating a static method.
Example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Customers"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerId = sdr["CustomerId"].ToString(),
                        ContactName = sdr["ContactName"].ToString(),
                        City = sdr["City"].ToString(),
                        Country = sdr["Country"].ToString(),
                        PostalCode = sdr["PostalCode"].ToString(),
                        Phone = sdr["Phone"].ToString(),
                        Fax = sdr["Fax"].ToString(),
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
}
```

An easier alternative is to create a webservice (.ASMX) using instance methods.