# ("NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized) Calling code behind method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call code behind method from JS 
but it gives me this error

```
NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized
```

Here is the code behind method

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string ExtractToPDF(string FSID)
{
   return FSID;
}
```

and here is the JS Function

```
 function extractFile(FSID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Update.aspx/ExtractToPDF",
            data: "{"+FSID+"}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the response

```
{
"Message": "An error occurred during the processing of the request",
"StackTrace": "",
"ExceptionType": ""
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX "401 (Unauthorized)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code behind method needs to be static

Simple solution:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ExtractToPDF(string FSID)
{
    return FSID;
}
```