# ASP.Net jQuery AJAX call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to call a code-behind method on the click event for this button:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_submit1" class="btn btn-default" value="Calculate" />
```

Here's the AJAX call for it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn_submit1").click(function() {

        var msg = $("#txt_1_1").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Calc.aspx/calculate',
            data: '{sText:' + msg + '}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success!!");
                alert(response.d);
                $("#test").html(response.d);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Here's the WebMethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string calculate(string sText)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sText = " + sText);
        return sText;
    }
```

Both the alerts in the success part are being called, but the second one says "undefined" and so nothing is getting displayed in the div "test".
I've searched a lot but couldn't find what's wrong with the code.

And also, Debug.WriteLine does not print anything in the Output window. I used this after searching through the net, I'm not sure if it's the right way to print or not.

Comment: Presumably then `response.d` is undefined.  What is in `response`?  Why do you expect it to have a `d` property?

Comment: `"Debug.WriteLine does not print anything in the Output window"` - What output window?  This is a web application, they generally don't have console windows associated with them.

Comment: @Archer - console.log(data) shows this error in Chrome console - Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
However console.log(msg) displays whatever I had in the textbox "txt_1_1".

Comment: Sorry - my bad (force of habit).  Change it to `console.log(response);`  It will show you exactly what is being returned, rather than [object Object]

Comment: @Archer - Here's the message in console for console.log(response):
Object {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null, ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: @David: Yes, I read that Console.Writeline would not work, hence used this one.

Comment: @connoisseur: Right, but where do you expect `Debug.Writeline()` to output?  And your other comment indicates that an exception is being thrown server-side.  Which line throws that exception?  What are the details of that exception?

Comment: Have a look here - it may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized

Comment: @Archer - Nope. Got This:
POST https://localhost:44300/Calc.aspx/calculate 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8720
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8150
(anonymous function) @ Calc.aspx:114
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5109
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4780

Comment: @David - I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, perhaps I can get the details if you elaborate where to get it from. The Chrome console however points to this line: console.log(response)

Comment: The server error could be caused by many things, but one that leaps out is the structure of the data you're sending.  Change it to `data: JSON.stringify({ sText: msg }),`  You're currently passing a string with no delimiters around it.

Comment: @Archer - Still the same result.. :(
I think If I could find what the "calculate" WebMethod is receiving in the parameter, it could help further narrowing down the issue.. but Debug.WriteLine won't print anything.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The ".d" part of the response is a security feature that Microsoft added to ASP.NET 3.5 to encapsulate a JSON object. You can check if you need to use the ".d" by doing:

```
if (response.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
    console.log(response.d);
    var myData = $.parseJSON(response.d);
} else {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Edit: It's likely that in this case you do not need to use the ".d" because the data you are returning is not valid JSON and most likely a string.

Edit 2: From the internal server error you've mentioned in a comment it looks like your data may not be in the correct format. I'm just speculating here really but you might try:

```
var datapackage = {
    msg: $("#txt_1_1").val()
};
var datapacked = JSON.stringify(datapackage);
```

And then on the the AJAX call put "data: datapacked,".

Comment: Object {Message: "Authentication failed.", StackTrace: null, ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: Then I'm afraid it looks like the issue is with your ASP WebMethod. You might check out the answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized

Comment: Did not help. Got this error:
POST localhost:44300/Calc.aspx/calculate 500 (Internal Server Error) send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8150 (anonymous function) @ Calc.aspx:114 jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5109 elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4780

Comment: I've edited my answer again with something you could try... it may be that the error is resulting from incorrect JSON being passed in.

Comment: Nope. Still the same error. This is making me crazy now :@