# Charisma V.2.0.0 bundle in ASP.Net Ajax error

Tags: ajax, charisma

I've integrated the Charisma V.2.0.0 bundle in an ASP.Net C# application. All looks good until I write an .ajax call to a web service.  Ajax call, a standard format, works in a basic asp.net page, but from the bundle.  It seems like something in his 'bower_components'. I removed reference to bower_components/jquery and am including ajax.googleapis.com... 3.3.1.

Does anyone have experience with this problem? and what might be a solution?  I like the UI Muhammad designed and would like to keep developing which is platform.

The axax call looks like this:

```
 // Edit Client button
    $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnEditClient]", function () {
        // Edit selected client/Event Id - get data from Ajax
        //alert($(this).val());
        var clientId = $(this).val();
        var clientInfo = JSON.stringify({ clientId: clientId });
        alert(clientInfo);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("QRWebService.aspx/GetClientListService") %>',
                type: "POST",
                data: clientInfo,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    // results
                    alert(result.d);
                    alert('no error ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                    $("#myModal").modal()
                    return true;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('error: ' + textStatus);
                }
            });            

        return false;
    })
```

and the result is 'undefined' where the web service never gets called.

The web serivce is:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static DataSet GetClientListService()
    {
        // returns dataset LIST of Client Id and Name
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SQLHelper.SqlQuery oQuery = new SQLHelper.SqlQuery();
        String strSQL;

        try
        {
            strSQL = "SELECT Clients.ClientId, ClientName FROM Clients ";
            strSQL += "WHERE ClientActive=@clientActive";

            ds = oQuery.GetDataSet(strSQL);

        } catch(Exception ex){
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        return ds;
    }   // end GetClientEventList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Post [ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX "401 (Unauthorized)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized).  Changing the App_Start from Permanent to:

```
  settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

did the trick.  I hope this helps others.  Thank you StackOverflow and all those who post solutions to tricky issues.