# ASP.Net 3.5 WebMethod called using jQuery AJAX throws Unauthroized 401 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to call a web method using jQuery and having same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized), but I am working with ASP.Net 3.5 web forms, and don't have `~/App_start/routeconfig.cs`.

How can I fix this error with ASP.Net 3.5?

Comment: If you're getting a 401 error from a jQuery AJAX request the you need to include an `Authorization` header in the request, passing the auth token in whatever format is required. It's not a C# issue, unless you're not expecting to have any type of authentication at all, in which case you simply need to disable it.

Comment: ok .. so this error is at the login page. as I said I am having exact same issue.

Comment: have you tried this to send the session: [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Comment: @SehaxX, yes already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing that, you can adding below code in `web.config`:

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

For more information, please see [allow Element for authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is really in authorization, then try to allow an anonymous access to your login page in `web.config`:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```