# 401:unauthorized when I try to call a method via AJAX in .net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a .net project in the framework 4.5.1

When I use `ajax` like below, it works and the debugger hits the `page_load` event:

```
$.ajax({
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "Advanced.aspx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (ms) {
            alert('success');
        }
    })
```

In my **advanced.aspx.cs**, I have the method below:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
        public static string SaveChange(string myval)
        {
            //dummy code for test purposes.
            string u = myval + "X";
            return u;
        }
```

I want to hit this method via `ajax`. To do this, I am updating my `ajax` call like below:

```
$.ajax({
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "Advanced.aspx/SaveChange",
            data: {username:"test"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (ms) {
                alert('success');
            }
        })
```

However, it gives me `401:unauthorized error` when i do it in that way, shown below:

[image]

How can I fix this? Tried lots of things for the last few hours, no luck.. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've used `async` and `crossDomain` hoping to fix this issue, didn't help. Normally they don't exist in my ajax call, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX "401 (Unauthorized)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)

I have used 
`settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;` instead of `RedirectMode.Permanent` in `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`, which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your AJAX JS to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Advanced.aspx/SaveChange",
    data: {myval:"test"},
    success: function (ms) {
        alert('success');
    }
})
```